# An irreducible Weil(-Deligne) representation is automatically semisimple

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, langlands-program

Let $(V,r,N)$ be an irreducible Weil-Deligne representation. By irreducibility, $N=0$ automatically. Is it true that the Frobenius element acts semisimply?

This is not true if we only assume that the representation is indecomposable. The tate module of an elliptic curve that has semistable but not good reduction is such an example.

Definitions:

Let $F$ be a local field, $\Gamma_F$ it's Galois group and $I_F$ the Inertia subgroup. Recall that there is an exact sequence:
$$0 \to I_F \to \Gamma_F\to \hat {\mathbb Z} \to 0.$$
The Weil group $W_F \subset \Gamma_F$ is the inverse image of $\mathbb Z\subset \hat{\mathbb Z}$. A Weil-Deligne representation is a representation $r$ of $W_F$ on a $\mathbb C$ vector space $V$ so that $r(I_F)$ is finite and some technical condition on $N$ that we ignore here because it turns out be zero in the irreducible case anyway.

Comment: I edited in some details.

Comment: You can make things more concrete assuming $F = Q_p$ and that $L=F^{\ker(r) \cap I_F}$ is a finite tamely ramified extension of $Q_p^{unr} = \bigcup_{p \nmid n} Q_p(\zeta_n)$ then $L = Q_p^{unr}(p^{1/l})$, let $g\in Gal(L/Q_p), g(\zeta_n)=\zeta_n^p$ then $g(p^{1/l})=\zeta_l^ap^{1/l}$ and $\pi =  (\zeta_l^a)^{1/(1-p)} p^{1/l}$ is an uniformizer of $L$ which is fixed by $g$.

Comment: Is it not the case that Frobenius acting semisimply is equivalent to $r$ being semisimple as a representation of $W_F$?

Comment: Yes, that is true @mathmo123

Comment: @Asvin Can you clarify what the question is? If $r$ is irreducible, then it is semisimple, and therefore Frobenius semisimple. What am I missing?

Comment: Or is the question about the Weil-Deligne representation associated to an irreducible Weil representation? (In which case, the answer is yes)

Comment: I guess I know the proof that Frobenius semisimple implies r is semisimple but not the other direction.

Comment: @mathmo123 is there a reference for the yes?